# libmysql.dll where do you get this?

Tags: php, mysql

Where do you download that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want it for, but [here](http://www.dll-files.com/pop.php?dll=libmysql) is the result of a quick google search.

Answer (score 0):

A complete package is available at http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: I doubt he wants it for PHP. libmysql.dll is not the PHP MySQL API but the DLL which can be used by "real" programs.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Well he tagged the post PHP