# Not able to find ‘libmysql.dll’ file in the installed PHP directory

Tags: php

In the process of installing php (5.4.14) from php.net, I extracted the zip file but now I am not able to find ‘libmysql.dll’ file in the installed PHP directory. Do I need to install the file from the third party?

Comment: see this link may be help you to slove your problem. [libmysql.dll where do you get this?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980980/libmysql-dll-where-do-you-get-this

Answer (score 0):

libmysql.dll is part of the MySQL (client) distribution. Make sure that MySQL (client) is properly installed